# How to change FlowFile name to XML-row tag after splitting XML in NIFI?

Tags: xml, bigdata, apache-nifi

I devided a large XML file into 237 smaller files by using the `SplitXML`-Processor. As a basis, I used the children of the roots.

Now I want to give each resulted file their corresponding XML row tag as filename.

For example, following structure results in files named `Package`, `Billing`, `Policy` and so on...

```xml
    root
     |-- Package: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- package12: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Addr: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- Addr1: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- Addr2: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Billing: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- PhlyRepresentativeEmail: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Policy: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- PolicyName: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the "new root" of each FlowFile by directing them into a `ExtractText`-Processor. Then you use RegEx to pull the corresponding tag and store it into a specific variable.

See
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExtractText/ for more